# Displaying a cell always at least at the bottom of the screen

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, tableview, swift4

We got UI specs for a change in a page with a table view. The last cell of this table view should be at the bottom of the page. However, if the table view content is longer then the page, then the cell should scroll.

Here are two approaches that I have tried, with success:

1. Have a UIView of the cell content with a constraint to the bottom of the page, as well as the cell in the table view. If the table view content height < the view height, hide the cell from the table view and use the UIView instead.
2. Have a buffer cell between the rest of the table view and the final cell. In the viewDidAppear, since it seems to be the place where the table view elements have their height, get the sum of the height of the other cells of the table view. If this sum is smaller then the screen  size, set screen size - cellsHeight to a View controller variable, and trigger a table view reload. In the heightForCellAtIndexPath function, when rendering the buffer cell, use the variable's height to define the buffer height. In the first calculation it will be 0. in the second table view calculations , it will be 0 if the cell need to scroll, or whatever the calculation returned if it needs a buffer.

I feel like both of these solutions are dirty. Are there any better way to approach this problem? If not, is there a way to run the second solution without two data reloading?

Comment: It's hard to provide a complete solution without a visual representation of the problem, see [asking good questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) Check your constraints for the bottom of the tableView, ensure the content is inset to the scrollView. i.e. `tableView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0, 12, 0);`

Comment: posting this as a comment for food for thought, could you use a tableFooterView to accomplish this? Might need some more dirty magic though to adjust the height on a small table though

Comment: If you have to stick to a UITableViewCell, then your solutions are about as clean as it will get.  You could possibly have the cell automatically check its visibleRect's parent hierarchy against its own frame and adjust its height by itself if it doesn't reach the bottom; this way the behaviour of the resizing is all contained within this cell code and not in your view controller.